# How to concat_ws multiple fields and remove duplicate separators for empty slots

Tags: sql, mysql, concatenation

When you `CONCAT_WS(' ',field1,field2,field3)` in MySQL and if one of the fields is empty, not null, you get multiple separators.

An example can be:

```
John[space][space][space]Doe[space]III.
```

How can I make sure there is only one separator.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
CONCAT_WS(' ', NULLIF(field1, ''), NULLIF(field2, ''), NULLIF(field3, ''));
```

`CONCAT_WS` will skip any null values, and by using `NULLIF` any empty ones too.

Note: You can't regex replace. MySQL does not support it.