# Conditional CONCAT with potentially NULL or empty values

Tags: mysql

In the below piece of code, I am creating an Address field by concatenating various parts of an address.

However, if for instance `address2` was empty, the trailing `,` will still be concatenated into Address.

This means if all fields were empty, I end up with a result of `,,,,`.

If `address1` is `"House Number"` and everything else is empty, I end up with `House Number,,,,`.

```
CONCAT( COALESCE(address1,'')   ,   ', '    , 
        COALESCE(address2,'')   ,   ', '    , 
        COALESCE(address3,'')   ,   ', '    , 
        COALESCE(city,'')       ,   ', '    , 
        COALESCE(zip, '')
) AS Address,
```

Is there some way of conditionally placing the commas between address parts only if the content of an address part is not empty.

Such as something along the lines of (pseudo-code) `IF(address1) is NULL use '' ELSE use ','`

Thank you.

Comment: For a more simple answer, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924657/how-to-concat-ws-multiple-fields-and-remove-duplicate-separators-for-empty-slots . I had posted the answer from there here too, but was deleted by a mod.

Answer (score 66):

```
CONCAT_WS(', ',
        IF(LENGTH(`address1`),`address1`,NULL),
        IF(LENGTH(`address2`),`address2`,NULL),
        IF(LENGTH(`address3`),`address3`,NULL),
        IF(LENGTH(`city`),`city`,NULL),
        IF(LENGTH(`zip`),`zip`,NULL)
)
```

Comment: This solution is elegant. The use of the LENGTH function to return NULL, which gracefully handles the situation where an empty string is present. An empty string is not NULL, so concat_ws would incorrectly include a delimitor ahead of empty strings. Very nice!

Comment: And from a user @Martin who has only answered one question on stackoverflow, with just 11 reputation points. I'm humbled.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Exactly what I was looking for. saved lot of time

Comment: Nice to see example here.

Answer (score 5):

Using `CONCAT_WS` as Mat says is a very good idea, but I thought I'd do it a different way, with messy `IF()` statements:

```
CONCAT( COALESCE(address1,''), IF(LENGTH(address1), ', ', ''), 
        COALESCE(address2,''), IF(LENGTH(address2), ', ', ''), 
        COALESCE(address3,''), IF(LENGTH(address3), ', ', ''), 
        COALESCE(city,''), IF(LENGTH(city), ', ', ''), 
        COALESCE(zip,''), IF(LENGTH(address1), ', ', ''), 
) AS Address,
```

The `IF()`s check if the field has a length and if so returns a comma. Otherwise, it returns an empty string.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this works fine, but as you point out, using CONCAT_WS is even simpler so I've stuck with that.

Answer (score 5):

try with [`MAKE_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_make-set)

```
SELECT MAKE_SET(11111,`address1`,`address2`,`address3`,`city`,`zip`) AS Address
```

It will returns a string with all NOT NULL value separated by `,`

Answer (score 2):

```
CONCAT_WS(', ',
        NULLIF(`address1`,''),
        NULLIF(`address2`,''),
        NULLIF(`address3`,''),
        NULLIF(`city`,''),
        NULLIF(`zip`,'')
)
```

- CONCAT_WS combines non-NULL strings.
- NULLIF writes NULL if left and right side are equals. In this case if values are equals an empty sting ''.

Comment: This answer works across just about any database, with null or empty fields, and is awesome and should be accepted as the answer.